# Install FreeIPA on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-ec2, sssd, freeipa, amazon-linux

The goal is to install "freeipa" on Amazon Linux 2023 AMI.

Amazon Linux 2023 doesn't officially support the package by default, due to this AMI is made of Fedora 34, 35, 36, and CentOS 9 Stream, I tried to install fedora package repository and install `ipa-client` from this.

I created a new file under `/etc/yum.repos.d` with the following code

```
[fedora] name=Fedora repository
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-37&arch=x86_64 
priority=9 
enabled=1 
repo_gpgcheck=0 
type=rpm 
gpgcheck=0
```

I run `yum install ipa-client --allowerasing` and it was successful.

Then I tried to configured the ipaclient running the following comand which is working fine in amazon linux 2 AMIs

```
ipa-client-install \
-U \
--domain="mydomain.com" \
--force \
--force-join \
--hostname="$(hostname -s).mydomain.com" \
--mkhomedir \
--nisdomain="mydomain.com" \
--realm="MYDOMAIN.COM" \
--password="${password}" \
--principal="${user}" \
--server="${server}.mydomain.com"
```

And I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ipa-client-install", line 22, in <module>
    from ipaclient.install import ipa_client_install
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipaclient'
```

Has anyone managed to install the FreeIPA client and successfully onboard the host to the IPA domain?

Comment: I managed to get it working just recently! It took a lot of patience… I had to backport/update a ton of RPM files to get the right combo of things. I'm hoping to have something to share soon, but I have ADHD and dunno when the hell I will.

Answer (score 0):

As of today - 2023-12-12 - you must use packages that Amazon does not currently provide in order to get FreeIPA working.

Unfortunately, this means that you're going to have to look for SRPMS for other distros, then update the spec files so they compile properly on Amazon Linux 2023.

I had to do this myself just a couple weeks ago, and it sucked.

So I've made the specs and SRPMS I used available just now at https://github.com/livingstaccato/freeipa-amzn2023

Good luck!